# How can I make Ubuntu check for updates less often?

Tags: updates

I'd like to have Ubuntu not check for updates as often. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### For 10.10 and earlier versions (and 11.04, in an Ubuntu Classic session)

Open Update Manager (*System* > *Administration* > *Update Manager*).

On the Updates tab, there's a drop down box for "Check for updates:", with options for Daily, every two days, weekly or every two weeks.

Or you can turn it off and just check manually whenever you want.

Comment: I think you meant "Software Sources", not "Update Manager"

Answer (score 30):

### For 11.04 and higher

1. Start **System settings.**
   Either search for it in **dash** or click on the **gear** in the top right corner. 
   [image]
2. click on **Software sources**
   [image]
3. Choose **updates**
   [image]
4. now choose how often you want to check for updates.
   [image]

### For people in a hurry!

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and search as shown and click `software-properties-gtk`, then jump to step 3.

**OR** open a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, and type `software-properties-gtk`, then jump to step 3.

[image]

### Via the Ubuntu software center

If you are more comfortable with using the USC then you could open it, and click on **edit** and then at the bottom **software sources**. Now just go to step 3.

Comment: oooooooo..... arrows....

Comment: Hey Alvar not fair. You are using the old "arrow pointing to answer" trick.

Comment: I find it very confusing that your arrows change color throughout the tutorial. What is the significance of the red over the blue? You should add a disclaimer outlining this information. :P

Comment: @rlemon I actually edited the arrows from the fourth one to the first one and when I got there I realized that a blue arrow on a blue background wouldn't look that great, so I made it red. It's of no significant of any sort. :)

Answer (score 5):

System -> Administration -> Software Sources -> Updates (tab) -> Check for updates: [Daily | Every two days | Weekly | Every two weeks]

Answer (score 3):

And if I want to check monthly?
Where are stored this settings?

I don't see this on /etc/update-manager

---

Ok, now I've found this meaning file in Ubuntu 10.10:
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic