# How can I tell the update dialog box from showing while I am doing some presentaion or etc?

Tags: updates, update-manager

Ubuntu 12.04 i am using, often without my command, it shows following:

[image]

How can i permanently stop/disable/kill this, using command line?

(every-time it pop-ups like i am showing my own presentation, or i  left my PC for idle longer and came back to give my lecture, this Popup shows, which is very very annoying in many use case i had).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On that Update Manager dialogue, click "Settings".

Then, next to the option "Automatically check for updates", use the drop-down list to select "Never".
"
You can still get updates by opening Update Manager yourself and clicking "Check", or by using `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade`, but it won't pop up by itsself any more.

From the command line you need to edit the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic`

I believe changing all those options to "0" will result in the behaviour you expect.

- [How can I make Ubuntu check for updates less often?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14/how-can-i-make-ubuntu-check-for-updates-less-often)

Comment: My system is located remotely somewhere. And i only have SSH access, SSH port no remote VNC etc. Can i not do it with command line?

Comment: Never mind, I edited the comment